# Conversion: Binary Search Tree to Doubly Linked List

Tags: binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

I am converting a binary search tree to a doubly linked list and using recursion for the same. However, the recursion never ends and gives me a StackOverFlow error. I am not able to understand where I've gone wrong.
Here is the code I've written.

```
/* Binary Search Tree to Doubly Linked List conversion*/

static Node root2;

 // head --> Pointer to head node of created doubly linked list
 static Node head;

 // Initialize previously visited node as NULL. This is
 // static so that the same value is accessible in all recursive
 // calls
 static Node prev = null;

 // A simple recursive function to convert a given Binary tree 
 // to Doubly Linked List
 // root --> Root of Binary Tree
 void BinaryTree2DoubleLinkedList(Node root2) 
 {
     // Base case
     if (root2 == null){
         return;
     }

     // Recursively convert left subtree
    BinaryTree2DoubleLinkedList(root2.left);

     // Now convert this node
     if (prev == null) 
         head = root2;
     else
     {
         root2.left = prev;
         prev.right = root2;
     }
     prev = root2;

     // Finally convert right subtree
     BinaryTree2DoubleLinkedList(root2.right);
 }

 /* Function to print nodes in a given doubly linked list */
 void printList(Node node)
 {
     while (node != null) 
     {
         System.out.print(node.data + " ");
         node = node.right;
     }
 }
```

However when I'm populating my BST, as soon as I enter two values, it gives me a StackOverlow Exception.
Can anybody please take a look at this?

Comment: Can you give some background about what heuristic you want to use when converting the binary tree?  For example, if the trees were `ROOT -- A, B`, then would the list be `A -- B` or `B -- A` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's supposed to be A -- B. It doesn't matter though, does it? With the exception I mean